# Comparing meaning of first order logical statements

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I came across simple problem as follows:

> For each pair of predicate calculus formulae below, either show that they are equivalent, or illustrate by choosing a
> simple domain and meaning for the predicate symbols that the two statements have different meanings.
> (a) $(∀xP(x)) ∨ (∀yQ(y)) ,\quad  ∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))$
> (b) $(∃xQ(x)) → (∃yP(y)) , \quad ∃x(Q(x) → P(x))$

I am able to solve it as follows:

> **For (a):**
> $P(x):$ $x$ has height more than 6 ft.
> $Q(x):$ $x$ has height less than 6 ft.
> Then, $(∀xP(x)) ∨ (∀yQ(y))$ means all people "considered together" either has height more than 6 ft OR less than 6 ft. This does not allow John to have height more than 6 ft and Roger to have height less that 6 ft.
> $∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))$ means everyone "considered individually" either has height more than 6 ft OR less than 6 ft. This allow John to have height more than 6 ft and Roger to have height less that 6 ft.
> Thus statements in (a) are not equivalent.

> **For (b)**:
> $Q(x):x$ is a husband
> $P(x):x$ is a wife
> Then, $(∃xQ(x)) → (∃yP(y))$ means for some husband $x$, there is wife $y$
> $∃x(Q(x) → P(x))$ means for some husband $x$, he is also wife (of himself), which does not makes sense.

**Q1.** Are above reasoning correct?

More importantly, can I solve it algebraically, for example by reducing them to   conjunctive normal form (CNF) and then comparing?

I tried it as follows:

> **For (a):**
> $∀xP(x)) ∨  (∀yQ(y)\equiv P(x)\vee Q(y)$
> $∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))\equiv P(x) \vee Q(x)$
> Obviously above two are not the same.

Am I correct with above.

> **For (b):**
> $(∃xQ(x)) → (∃yP(y))$
> $\equiv \neg (∃xQ(x)) \vee (∃yP(y)) $
> $\equiv (\forall x \neg Q(x))\vee (\exists y P(y))$
> $\equiv \neg Q(x)\vee P(B)$  (...skolemized)(equation 1)
> $∃x(Q(x) → P(x))$
> $\equiv ∃x(\neg Q(x) \vee P(x))$
> $\equiv \neg Q(A) \vee P(B))$  (...skolemized)(equation 2)

Above I somewhat applied skolemization rules as I understood them. For existential quantifier, we have to introduce variable (written in caps) for its operand. We can eliminate universal quantifier without changing its operand.

**Q2.** With variables in caps and in small case, how can I makes clear sense that equations 1 and 2 are different?

**Q3.** Or am I completely wrong with above CNF approach?

Answer (score 1):

Just for Q1:
the reasoning in part (a) looks good, but not in part (b).

To express the two implications in English, the important word "if" is missing. The first would be "If there is a husband then there is a wife". But the example interpretation does not work in showing the formulas are not equivalent. You seem to imagine a domain where some individuals are husbands, some are wives, none are both, and possibly some are neither. In this case your second formula will be true because the $x$ in the second can be any individual who is not a husband.

Comment: Is this correct for (b): $(∃xQ(x))→(∃yP(y))$ will be "if there exists some husband, then there exists some wife." and $∃x(Q(x)→P(x))$ will be "if there exists some husband, then he is wife". Former sounds correct, while later not and definitely the two does not sound same. Right?

Comment: The English you give fits the formulas now. Second does sound odd. But interpreting the formulas in the real world both are actually logically true! The 1st because these roles do come in pairs and the second because you can find someone who is not a husband. Remember $A \to B$ is true when $A$ is false (and separately when $B$ is true). The English version sounds incorrect because the way we use "if - then -" in everyday speech does not match the logical meaning of $\to$. You can read about "material implication" to learn more.

Comment: Ohh!!! so in real world second holds when someone is not husband, but not when he is husband. But this fact does not determine equivalence of the two parts. Those two parts are simply not the same in their meaning, right?

Comment: There is a good sense in which the two mean different things in English. But to show the formulas are not equivalent you need an interpretation where one is true and the other false. Your example does not do that: both are true. Try $Q(x)$ as in part (a): $x$ less than 6ft.  But say $P(x)$ means $x$ is more than 60ft tall. No human is over sixty feet tall.  If we are only talking about humans, your first formula in (b) is false. The second is true because we can take $x$ to be someone for whom $Q(x)$ is false, that is someone who is over 6ft.